# How to run Ricochet chat on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line

I've downloaded from https://ricochet.im/ the package for Linux. 
After unpacked, I move in the app's directory and type in a terminal: ./ricochet but nothing happens, only this error message "bash: ./ricochet: no such file or directory"

How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any packages on that website, so please edit your question to clarify exactly what you installed and how you installed it.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't understand what "no such file or directory" means? Or are you saying something else? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Ricochet is in the Bionic Repositories: `sudo apt-get install ricochet-im` should get it easily installed for you...